# CanvasJS with Vue.Js - Updating JSON data on mousemove

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm quite new to the `Vue.Js` framework. I'm trying to convert one of my graphs for use with `Vue.Js`

It is a `CanvasJS` donut chart. On `mousemove`, I want to call `donutChartMousemove` function, but I get this error

[image]

And this is a link to what I currently have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-column-chart-vuejs-vmksxn

Here is my original chart in `javascript` working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/1mxq972o/1/

Comment: There are many problems here. 1) You don't access a Vue instances data via the `data` property. 2) Arrays do not have a `set` method

Comment: `chart_parent.chart.subtitles[0].set("text", e.dataPoint.label + " (" + e.dataPoint.y + "%)");` will work, because you've placed the chart instance in the `chart` property of your Vue instance. See it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-column-chart-vuejs-hdmctb?file=index.js). But it's an anti-pattern as far as Vue principles go. The least you could do is place `donutChartMousemove` inside the Vue instance, as a method.

Comment: @tao Thank you, it seems obvious in hindsight.  @Phil Using the `data` property is my next milestone. The `set` is a CanvasJS method

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `this` is not available in `data`, in a Vue component. Your config has to come from a computed to be able to use methods inside it. I'll update the blitz. Edit: Now it's working (vue way :)). Cheers!